# Cannot compile code using an enum declared in a templated base class [C++]

Tags: c++, templates, enums

The following code (included in a single header file) is simple demonstration of the problem I encounter:

```
template <class T>
class A
{
public:
    enum Type
    {
        ONE,
        TWO
    };

    A( Type tp = ONE ):tp(tp) {

    }

protected:
    Type tp;
};

template <class T>
class B : public A<T>
{

    B( Type _tp ):A<T>(_tp) {

    }

};
```

This produces the compilation error (in Clang)

```
Untitled 2.cpp:24:4: error: unknown type name 'Type'
        B(Type _tp ):A<T>(_tp) {
          ^
1 error generated.
```

If I instead move the enum outside the scope of `A`, or remove the templatization of `A` and `B`, then the above code compiles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your enum is going to be that simple, it would probably be best to simply move it outside `A<T>`, as you already indicated worked -- you could keep it in a namespace if you'd like. Otherwise, the enum is inside the class `A<T>` and so inside `B`, `Type` in an incomplete name. Instead,

```
template <class T>
class B : public A<T>
{

    B( typename A<T>::Type _tp )
      : A<T>(_tp)
    {
    }

};
```

The `typename` keyword is required because `A` is templated.

Comment: Thank you so much jwimberley